# partial removal of string on a variable whilst keeping other variables in the data frame R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use gsub() on the observations of a single variable in a data frame (df1). I'd like to remove everything before "-" in var1, whilst keeping var2 and var3, so that I end up with something like df3. Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point (df):

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=c("QJR - W5_COV","BJR - UMMY_SITE","KSJA_DSD - R0101","KSJA_DSD - LS300"),var2=c(1,1,1,1),var3=c("KSJA_DSD - hi","bye","KSJA_DSD - WS700","bit"))
```

Desired outcome (df):

```
df3 <- data.frame(var1=c("W5_COV","UMMY_SITE","R0101","LS300"),var2=c(1,1,1,1),var3=c("KSJA_DSD - hi","bye","KSJA_DSD - WS700","bit"))
```

Current code: Var1 looks good but I lose the other variables.

```
df2 <- gsub(".*-","",df1$var1)
```

Comment: Try `df2$var1 <- gsub(".*-","",df1$var1)`

Comment: Thanks joran, I went with df1$var1 <- gsub(".*-","",df1$var1), I'm sure that's what you meant.